# getting green screen in video streaming through Janus and Gstreamer

Tags: ubuntu, gstreamer, janus, janus-gateway

[image]I am using Janus and Gstreamer to show the live video from my usb camera .

we are using this script for getting video and send through network `gst-launch-0.10 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 queue-size=4 always-copy=false ! "video/x-raw-yuv, format=(fourcc)UYVY, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, interlaced=(boolean)false, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1" ! nvvidconv ! "video/x-nv-yuv, format=(fourcc)I420, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080" ! nv_omx_h264enc ! rtph264pay mtu=60000 ! udpsink clients=192.168.6.89:5000 sync=false -e`

i got the video in my webpage .but its come up with the green screen .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'green' color indicates uninitialized memory in YUV formats. This could eg. be the nvvidconv not filling all pars of the buffer.

In any case you are using 0.10 of gstreamer which hasn't seen updates for more than 5 years. I'd suggest to use 1.X.

Answer (score 0):

just update the Gstreamer and manage  the packet size .

rtph264pay mtu=60000.
mtu should be managed.